# Getting nearest previous date, sort without modifying original array

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm trying to get the nearest date to `formatted_date`=2020-08-04 in this way, where the nearest is the previous one --> `2020-08-02`

```js
var arrayDateValue= [];
var formattedDate = '2020-08-04';
arrayDateValue.push({
        date: '2020-08-01',
        value: 1111     });
arrayDateValue.push({
        date: '2020-08-02',
        value: 1212     });
arrayDateValue.push({
        date: '2020-08-05',
        value: 1313     });
arrayDateValue.push({
        date: '2020-08-06',
        value: 1313     });



var prevIndexIfNotFound = arrayDateValue
.sort((a, b) => (new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date)))
.findIndex(date => new Date(date.date) - new Date(formattedDate) <= 0);

console.log(arrayDateValue[prevIndexIfNotFound]);
```

The result is perfect, but -

1. I need `arrayDateValue` to further process, how to sort it without modifying it?
2. The processing time is a little bit slower when my array is big, is there efficient way to optimize such requests?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So loop over all the dates and check to see if the difference and keep track. No need to sort.

```js
var arrayDateValue = [];
var formattedDate = '2020-08-04';
arrayDateValue.push({
  date: '2020-08-01',
  value: 1111
});
arrayDateValue.push({
  date: '2020-08-02',
  value: 1212
});
arrayDateValue.push({
  date: '2020-08-05',
  value: 1313
});
arrayDateValue.push({
  date: '2020-08-06',
  value: 1313
});

const closest = arrayDateValue.reduce( (obj, item) => {
  const diff = new Date(item.date) - new Date(formattedDate);
  if (diff < 0 && (!obj || obj.diff < diff)) {
    return { item, diff }
  }
  return obj
},  null)

if (closest) console.log(closest.item);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting, but suppose my var formattedDate = '2020-08-05'; is an existing date, no need to search for previous, do you think that this is the best way ?
if (diff == 0) {
    return { item, diff }
  } else if (diff < 0 && (!obj || obj.diff < diff)) {
    return { item, diff }
  }

Answer (score 1):

> 1. I need `arrayDateValue` to further process, how to sort it without
>    modifying it?

You could avoid mutating the original array by just using the **spread operator syntax**(`...`) to create a copy of the array and then sort it so that the original array stays the same. It can be done just by adding a single line of code as -

```js
var arrayDateValue= [];
var formattedDate = '2020-08-04';
arrayDateValue.push({
        date: '2020-08-01',
        value: 1111     });
arrayDateValue.push({
        date: '2020-08-02',
        value: 1212     });
arrayDateValue.push({
        date: '2020-08-05',
        value: 1313     });
arrayDateValue.push({
        date: '2020-08-06',
        value: 1313     });


// to avoid mutating original array
var copiedArr = [...arrayDateValue]
var prevIndexIfNotFound = copiedArr
.sort((a, b) => (new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date)))
.findIndex(date => new Date(date.date) - new Date(formattedDate) <= 0);

console.log(copiedArr[prevIndexIfNotFound]);
```

You can read more about spread syntax if you don't know about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

---

> 2. The processing time is a little bit slower when my array is big, is there an efficient way to optimize such requests?

The same can be done using a single iteration through the `arrayDateValue` array. A simple way would be to write a **parse and compare function** which would take in *date* parameter and split it into a `year`, `month` and `day` variable which could then be used to compare against our `result` variable which would be initialized at the start and modified at each iteration to store the closest date using the above-mentioned function.

I suggest you try to code the above logic and revert back if you find any difficulty in doing so.

Comment: oh this is nice, but I think that, in fact, the function lost its works once array become immutable --> value 2020-08-05, sadly !

Comment: @ranell Sorry, I forgot to do an edit. The function was returning the correct index but while console logging, I was using the old non-mutated array which is why it was giving the wrong result. Now it's been corrected. Check the edit where I am using `copiedArr` to log to console